# Hide multiple Dropdown boxs using CSS for printing

Tags: c#, jquery, css, media-queries

On my c# mvc page, I have several dropdown boxs displayed on the page, I'm using media query to render the view differently for print and screen.

My question is that is there a way (using CSS) to hide ALL the dropdown boxs if the selected option value is "". (the text for that value is '< Select >').

So that when printing, the following will be printed:

```
Title
```

Instead of:

```
Title < Select >
```

Just want to make it more clear,

if the selected option is not "" then I do need to display it when printing,
so the following:

```
Title Mr
```

will display as the same when printing as:

```
Title Mr
```

Here is one of my dropdown:

```
<select id="Alias_Title" name="Alias.Title">
    <option value="">< Select ></option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
</select>
```

Don't know whether this is achievable or not with CSS, if not, can it be done by Jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is a combination of @Satpal and @General-Doomer 's answer to the question.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('select').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() == "";
    }).addClass('hidden-print');

    $('select').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-print');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden-print');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS class:

```
.hidden-print{
  display: none !important;
}
```

The filter() function works for when user try to print the page without touch any of the dropdown boxs.
The change() function works for when user try to print the page after changing the value of dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.fn.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find all the select whose value is "" then add a hidden class

```
$(function () {
    $('select').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() == "";
    }).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Add a CSS class

```
.hidden{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work? it makes all dropdown boxs display as < Select > on the page regardless of Screen or Print mode

Comment: @Justin, Here I am not setting any value

Comment: Hi @Satpal, I added the following to the top of my page:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('select').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() == "";
        }).addClass('hidden');
    </script>

Comment: @Justin, http://jsfiddle.net/on5tjj7e/ You didn't use document-ready handler, use updated code

Comment: thanks, your solution works when all the dropdown boxs have been pre-selected.  General-Doomer 's solution works after user selected a value for the dropdown box. I have combined the solutions from you guys to achieve what I want.

    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {  
    $('select').filter(...);  
    $('select').change(...);  
    }
    </script>

Now I am new to StackOverFlow, can I make both of your answers as the selected answer?

Answer (score 1):

CSS for print (from BootStrap)

```
@media print {
  .visible-print-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

@media print {
  .hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Elements with `hidden-print` CSS class are not visible for printing.

Code:

```
<select id="Alias_Title" name="Alias.Title" class="hidden-print">
    <option value="">&lt; Select &gt;</option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('select').change(function () {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    $(this).addClass('hidden-print');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('hidden-print');
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: this will make all other dropdown boxs not printing who has valid option selected

Comment: I have edited my answer and added script for adding hidden-print class when user selects empty value.

Comment: your solution works after user selected a value for the dropdown box. Satpal 's solution works when all the dropdown boxs have been pre-selected. I have combined the solutions from you guys to achieve what I want. 

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('select').filter(...); 
    $('select').change(...); 
} 
</script>`

Now I am new to StackOverFlow, can I make both of your answers as the selected answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can write like this.

```
if($('#Alias_Title').val().length == 0) { // int value
    $('#Alias_Title').hide();
 }
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that I want to hide several dropdown boxs altogether, I already tried

    if($(:select).val().length == 0) { // int value
        $(select).hide();
     }

but it hides all other dropdown boxs as well who's value is not empty

Comment: obviosuly it will hide, because you havent specified the id "#Alias_Title"